# Clear Angular modules in unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs

I'm doing some multi user testing for my AngularJS controllers, as my users have different roles and settings. The first one always works great, but subsequent attempts never issue attempts for HTTP mock requests, as the controllers are singletons. Is there any way for me to clear out all existing controllers, or even the whole Angular module setup and start it back up again so I can perform these types of tests?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried creating your controller in a beforeEach function? This way your controller will be recreated for each test.

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $location) {
    root = $rootScope;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    location = $location;
    controller = $controller('AccountInfoController', { $scope: scope, $location:$location, customer: customer });
}));
```

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I'm already doing:           
          var $scope = $rootScope.$new();

          return { controller: $controller(controllerName, {
            $scope: $scope,
            $routeParams: routeParams || {}
          }), scope: $scope };

Answer (score -1):

try this code if you want clear module

`angular.module('app',[]);`